# Read.table in R gives logical(0)

Tags: r

I am trying to read many files into R to evaluate the data in column 14 of each into its own histogram. It seems to work up until I try to access the actual data (aside from the column names.)

The code seems to work to an extent:

```
    test<-sapply(1:Num.Files,function(x){readLines(File.names[x])})
    head(test)
    data<-read.table(header=TRUE,text=test[1])
    head(data)
    names(data)[14]<-'column14'
    names(data)
    data$column14
```

but here is the result:

> test<-sapply(1:Num.Files,function(x){readLines(File.names[x])}) #Enters the data
>   head(test) #Can see here that the information is all there
>            [,1]
>       [1,] "Targ  cov  av_cov  87A_cvg  87Ag  87Agr  87Agr  87A_gra  87A%_1   87A%_3   87A%_5   87A%_10  87A%_20  87A%_30 87A%_40\t87A%_50\t87A%_75\t87A%_100"
>       [2,] "1:028 400\t0.42\t400\t0.42\t1\t1\t2\t41.8\t0.0\t0.0\t0.0\t0.0\t0.0\t0.0\t0.0\t0.0\t0.0"
>       [3,] "1:296 400\t0.42\t400\t0.42\t1\t1\t2\t41.8\t0.0\t0.0\t0.0\t0.0\t0.0\t0.0\t0.0\t0.0\t0.0"
>       [4,] "1:453 1646\t8.11\t1646\t8.11\t7\t8\t13\t100.0\t100.0\t87.2\t32.0\t0.0\t0.0\t0.0\t0.0\t0.0\t0.0"
>       [5,] "1:427 1646\t8.11\t1646\t8.11\t7\t8\t13\t100.0\t100.0\t87.2\t32.0\t0.0\t0.0\t0.0\t0.0\t0.0\t0.0"
>       [6,] "1:736 5105\t29.68\t5105\t29.68\t14\t29\t48\t100.0\t100.0\t100.0\t86.0\t65.7\t49.4\t35.5\t16.9\t0.0\t0.0"
>   data<-read.table(header=TRUE,text=test[1])
>   head(data) #all the correct column names
>        [1] Targ      cov       av_cov    X87A_cvg  X87Ag     X87Agr    X87Agr.1 
>        [8] X87A_gra  X87A._1   X87A._3   X87A._5   X87A._10  X87A._20  X87A._30 
>       [15] X87A._40  X87A._50  X87A._75  X87A._100
>       <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
>   names(data)[14]<-'column14'
>   names(data) #column 14 is changed as hoped
>        [1] "Targ"      "cov"       "av_cov"    "X87A_cvg"  "X87Ag"     "X87Agr"
>        [7] "X87Agr.1"  "X87A_gra"  "X87A._1"   "X87A._3"   "X87A._5"   "X87A._10" 
>       [13] "X87A._20"  "column14"  "X87A._40"  "X87A._50"  "X87A._75"  "X87A._100"
>   data$column14 #but there is nothing in the column
>       logical(0)

Am I using read.table incorrectly? Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: `head(data)` returns `<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)`, which means none of the columns have any data.

Comment: I think you want `read.table(file=test[1])` rather than `text=test[1]`.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich But head(test) has the information. How does it get lost between that and data<-read.table(header=TRUE,text=test[1])?

Comment: @Justin It does not seem to like that at all. > data<-read.table(file=test[1])
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
Calls: read.table -> file
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file 'Targ  cov  av_cov  87A_cvg  87Ag  87Agr  87Agr  87A_gra  87A%_1   87A%_3   87A%_5   87A%_10  87A%_20  87A%_30 87A%_40 87A%_50 87A%_7587A%_100': No such file or directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are using read.table incorrectly, you're passing it only the header line (`text[1]`).

I'd call `read.table` directly on the file names. If you insist on passing the result of `readLines`, you probably want to re-join everything like `paste(test, collapse="\n")`.

Comment: To pass all of it do I just leave text[] blank?

Answer (score 2):

why not just use `read.table` to begin with instead of the `readLines` business?  try:

```
test <- lapply(File.names, read.table, header=TRUE, sep='\t')`.
```

Also, your variable `test` is a vector of rows.  the first row is the header.  you're passing only the first row `test[1]` as the argument to `read.table(text=...)`.

using `read.table(text=test)` should work better.  However, you should probably use some variation on the `lapply` call that I wrote above instead of all this extra monkeying around.